# ARCGIS-JS-API : featurelayer.queryFeatures() not returning results

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a feature layer that is hosted on ArcServer. It has a field called `document_num` that is a string.

I have a table of which one of the columns is a link that lets the user "view on map". When this link is clicked it launches a function that is supposed to query the specific document by passing in the appropriate `document_num`..

The question is how should the where clause be formatted. I am having trouble getting the query to return any results. It is running though.

For example:
    If `document_num` = 100

```
function zoomToDoc(num){
    var query = new Query();
    var qString = "document_num" + num;
    query.where = qString;

    console.log(qTtring)

    (...)

    featureLayer.queryFeatures(query,......)
}
```

The `console.log()` in the above script produces `"document_num=100"`. This runs successfully but returns no feature.

Should the where clause be structured such that quotes are wrapping the parameters? i.e. `"document_num = '100'"`   or    `"'document_num'='100'"`? I have tried all of the above but still return zero feature. And yes the number being supplied to the function is a valid entry.

Any thoughts as to where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for strings, the value needs to be quoted, use single quotes, like `document='100'` - there's an example in the API Reference https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/query-amd.html#where  (if you're using version 3.x).

One way to check is to use the rest services directory, e.g. https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3/query?where=SUB_REGION%3D%27Pacific%27&outFields=SUB_REGION&returnGeometry=false&f=html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using queryFeatures , you can create a queryTask with your feature layer . just create a query and pass it as input of QueryTask.

```
    var deferred = new Deferred();
    var queryTask = new QueryTask(featureLayerurl)
    var query = new Query();
     query.geometry = geometry;        
    query.where = "document='100'";
    query.returnGeometry = true;
    query.outFields = ["*"];

    return deferred = queryTask.execute(query).addErrback(function (response) {
        console.error(response);
        return null;
    }).addCallback(function (response) {
        return response;
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response;
    });
```

if you want to get the complete result , you have to pass query outfields like this

```
 query.outFields = ["*"];
```

or if you want to get a few columns only , you can set appropriate field names in outfield array, like this

```
 query.outFields = ["object_id"];
```